# How to boost your chances of getting an internship?

Tags: interviewing, internship, united-kingdom, graduate

As a recent UK business school postgraduate, what would be some best practices for boosting ones chances of getting an internship at a major company in the film or music industries? What is the most appropriate way to reach out to companies?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what would be some best practices for boosting ones chances of getting an internship at a major company in the film or music industries?

This may be a bit broad, but the logical way is to **foster your skills on music, filming, etc., so your profile may stand out more** in the eyes of possible recruiters of such industry.

Besides that and perhaps a recommendation from someone relevant in the industry there are few things you can do; as in any job the applicants should be measured on their skills and knowledge, so the best you can do is to prepare yourself for working in such industry (take courses on Music, or Film editing, etc.).

> What is the most appropriate way to reach out to companies?

**Check for companies that you would like and see if they have any job opening** or are hiring people. You can then proceed to apply to the ones you like.

You can also go the other way round, and **look for job openings on that industry regardless of what company it is**, and then do some research on them to decide if it's worth applying.

Also, you could try with a **contracting firm or similar**, some that can contact you with **jobs or companies in the music or film industry** and help you in the job-seeking process.

Comment: @user2347540 glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

[Indeed](https://www.indeed.co.uk) (which is one of the big jobs websites) has many listings for just this sort of thing and you can search and apply for them just as you would for a normal job opening.

[Here's](https://www.indeed.co.uk/Internship-Film-Production-jobs-in-England) a page of ones in the film industry. Different companies will have different requirements and application processes but guidance on this is usually included in the listing.

Beyond that the advice for how to boost your chances is basically the same as it is for a job - make sure your CV is up to date and highlights any relevant experience or education you have matching the role you are applying for and if the application is looking for a cover letter then you can use this to discuss why you think you would be of benefit to the organisation in the role and why you are interested in it.

Comment: Happy to help :)